# get reference to Multipage in contentURL page

Tags: .net, telerik

I am using RadTabstrip with RadMultipage.

I have 3 tabs with 3 pageviews. I am using ContentURL property of pageview to load the page as a main page’s content.

How do I get a reference to Main page’s controls  in content page ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this can be done 'directly' - I suspect it is the same as to reference controls from two different ASPX pages.